# Why is Firefox not respecting my plugin choices for AMR files?

Tags: sound, firefox, vlc, totem

I have been [trying to get AMR files, which is the default format of Evernote, to play in Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/q/230216/17041). If I download an AMR file to my computer, it plays fine with Totem (which I think is now called Videos...?) But AMR files do not play when embedded in a web site. At least not on the Evernote web site.

At first, my install of Firefox defaulted to trying to use VLC to play AMR files, but they would not play. So I tried to switch my plugin preference to Totem. There was no automatic Totem option, so I selected to open the files with `/usr/bin/totem`. Despite setting it that way, Firefox still insisted on opening with VLC. Eventually, I had to completely remove the VLC Mozilla plug in with Synaptic. Having done that, this is what I see when I open an audio file on the Evernote web site:

[image: no plugin]

Annoyingly, there is nowhere to click, nothing to do so that I can select a plugin.

In the Preferences, I have selected to use Totem:

[image: use totem]

... but this is having no effect.

I tried just making it so that AMR files download:

[image: just download]

... but that didn't change anything either. I still get the plugin error graphic above.

The only way I can play AMR files from Evernote is to go through a tedious process of viewing the source of the frame within the web page and text searching for the AMR extension and then copying and pasting that to a new window... that process is obviously too inefficient for dealing with many audio files.

I may just drop Evernote completely if the audio is going to be this much of a hassle.

Nonetheless, **the real question here is, why is Firefox not respecting my selections for how to handle these files?** Regardless of whether or not the VLC or Totem plugins can handle AMR files, if I say to download the files, that's what it should do, shouldn't it?

Update: [Here is an Evernote audio file that I shared](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s257/sh/95c18078-0d79-4df1-aeeb-4546735a312b/e25c7fc12e0c795edc0d7820f6e80fe2) so that people could test for themselves if they can get it to play.

Comment: If you could provide a link to one such file.

Comment: @falconer, Thanks for responding. I've edited the question to include a link to a test AMR file that is located on the Evernote web site.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the file.

With `browser-plugin-vlc` installed (`sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-vlc`) it plays without problem on my Lubuntu 13.10 but has a minor problem with Ubuntu 12.04. First you have to make sure that the plugin is allowed to execute by clicking on the "LEGO-brick" before the URL-bar. (For me it was allowed and I think it was for you too.) After this you will see the VLC-cone as the plugin loaded, but the controls are disabled on 12.04. You have to **right-click on the VLC-cone and select Play**. After this the plugin controls are no more disabled and the audio is played without problem.

The changes made in Firefox preferences for the preferred applications doesn't have any effect on embedded objects (that is the purpose of embedding) that is why it won't help in your case. From [mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/set-how-firefox-handles-different-file-types):

> Also, when a plugin is available to handle a content type and you choose a different action for that type, **Firefox will only take your chosen action when you access the type directly**. For example, you may choose to open these files with a media player application instead of using the plugin that is set to open it. In such cases, **your chosen application will be used for file downloads but, when the content type is embedded inside a web page, Firefox will continue to use the plugin to handle the content type**.

If you still can't make it work by right clicking on the VLC-plugin then something is broken in your plugin. Unfortunately I don't know any browser plugins which explicitly support amr on Ubuntu, but it can still be made playable. In this case you will have to install the *Force-Content Type* firefox addon and change the amr content-type to e.g. mp3 which will trick firefox to load the Totem plugin for the file, which will have no problem opening the amr file although it doesn't explicitly support it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate that what you're saying implies that AMR files are potentially playable if I can figure out why the plugin is not functioning correctly. However this does not address the core question I asked, which is, why am I not offered the option to download the AMR file if I select to download it in my Firefox preferences.

Comment: @DaveMG They are not potentially playable, they are playable, you just have to right click on the plugin and select play. It is not sure that the default disabled controls are a bug, it is possible that it was done by design. (Or didn't the right-click method work?) And I answered your *"core question"* too, in the 3rd paragraph, which I now extend with official source.